# FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() - How does it work?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have 3 questions about this:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()
```

1. According to spec, getInstance() returns instance of the FirebaseAuth
   class, but the getUid not function in this class. But it works. How ?
2. It seems that getUid generates unique ID if this is a new user but it
   is not written in the spec. How does this function work?
3. When does it throw exception or return null ?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo.html#getUid())

### public abstract String getUid ()

> Returns a user identifier as specified by the authentication provider.
>   For example, if this object corresponds to a Google user, returns a
>   Google user ID. For phone number accounts, the UID will be the
>   normalized phone number in E.164 format.

**When does it throw an exception or return null?**

This is handled inside the singleton and inside the method `getUid()`, I couldn't find out any documentation about the throws

In order to `getUid()` to work, you will need to first get the current user signed in to get the ID

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

You can prevent a null by checking first if the current user is != null or just use the AuthListener to check it

```
FirebaseAuth currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if(currentUser != null)
  String uid = currentUser.getUid();
```

Comment: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();  --> this will work. You can try @Gastón Saillén

Comment: But I don't understand how ID is generated if this new user ? @Gastón Saillén